# ORA-01403: no data found for Select into

Tags: oracle

I am getting `ORA-01403: no data found` exception for the following query. What are the possibilities of this error?

```
SELECT trim(name)
  INTO fullname
  FROM ( SELECT n.name
         FROM directory dir, store n
        WHERE dir.name = n.name
          AND dir.status NOT IN ('F', 'L', 'M')
        ORDER BY n.imp, dir.date)
  WHERE rownum <= 1;
```

How can I handle this error?

Comment: ORA-01403: no data found occurs when you SELECT INTO and no rows are returned.

Comment: You tell us.. Have you checked for data in directory where STATUS NOT                IN ('F','L','M')? Have you checked data in store for name fetched from directory?

Comment: Yes... i have checked both of the values. Getting at least one value.

Comment: there seems to be a **bug**, at least in our **`Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit`** environment with it!: `function bar return varchar2 as x dual%rowtype; begin select * into x from dual where 1=0; return 'test'; end;` **normally returns without an error and returning no results** :-/ .. just mentioned because **catching NO_DATA_FOUND explicitely works** here as mentioned in Sandeeps answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21186642/1915920

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Although you have put a WHERE condition, a better way would be to handle case of record not found or 'No Data Found' error. I would write above code with wrapping the `SELECT` statement with it's own `BEGIN/EXCEPTION/END` block.

Code could be something like this:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT trim(name) 
    INTO fullName
    FROM (
        SELECT n.name
        FROM directory dir, store n
        WHERE dir.name = n.name
        AND dir.STATUS NOT IN ('F','L','M')           
        ORDER BY n.imp, dir.date
    )
    WHERE rownum <= 1;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        fullName := NULL;
END;
```

Comment: How can I write that for this case?

Comment: Tried posting answer in comment, but it is losing indentation when posted as a comment. Hence added code snippet in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks. What happens if we didn't put `fullName = NULL;` in side the exception block?

Comment: That is just a place holder. You can handle this error as per your logic.

Comment: It would be better to select count(\*) of the query first, and don't query if no rows will be returned back.  Both ways work, but count(\*) can avoid throwing an exception.

Answer (score 22):

**If the standard exception handling** described by Sandeep **seems to much overhead** (like in my case) and you're **fine with a `NULL` or some individual *<not found>* value**), you might just transform it like this:

```
select  col  into  v_foo  from  bar  where 1=0  -- would provoke ORA-01403
```

=> no *ORA-01403* raised:

```
-- if NULL would be fine:

select  (select  col  from  bar  where 1=0)  into  v_foo  from dual

-- if individual "NOT_FOUND" value should be set to avoid standard exception handling:
--    (it depends on your col type, so it could e.g. be 'NOT_FOUND' or -1 
--     or to_date( 'yyyy-mm-dd', '2100-01-01') )

select  nvl(  (select  col  from  bar  where 1=0),  'NOT_FOUND'  )  into  v_foo  from dual
```

Comment: I tried this method (as it does seem nicer than catching an exception), but I got an error `ORA-00913: too many values` at the beginning of the subquery. 

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your Query

```
SELECT n.name
        FROM directory dir,
          store n
        WHERE dir.name            = n.name
        AND dir.STATUS NOT                IN ('F','L','M')           
        ORDER BY n.imp,
          dir.date
```

is not returning any rows

Answer (score 1):

If `dir.status` has any nulls in your table, then `not in` is probably not doing what you think it is. You may get zero rows even though you think you should get one or more rows. You can switch to `and not (dir.status in ('F,'L','M'))` instead of `dir.status not in ('F','L','M')`.

See [this](http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2007/02/25/not-in/) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

forget the exceptions... just use the dual table:

```
select (
SELECT trim(name)
  FROM ( SELECT n.name
         FROM directory dir, store n
        WHERE dir.name = n.name
          AND dir.status NOT IN ('F', 'L', 'M')
        ORDER BY n.imp, dir.date)
  WHERE rownum <= 1
) into fullname
from dual;
```

B-) that way if your query don't return anything the variable will be populated with null.