# Select into a variable with case statement in a for loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

The *foo* variable should be filled with a *select case* within a *for* loop and then put out. I used a *goto end_loop* reference inside an exception, so the loop can continue.
Before I put the exception, I had an ORA-01403 error. Now I have an ORA-01422 error. The other selects without the case statement worked fine.

```
declare
foo varchar2(2000); 
BEGIN   
   FOR rec IN (SELECT something FROM somewhere)  
    LOOP
        BEGIN
          Select case when attribute = 'something' then '1' end into foo from somewhere where some_condition;   
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Something' || foo);     
          EXCEPTION
           WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
               foo := NULL;
               goto end_loop;     
        END;
        <<end_loop>>
        null;
    END LOOP; 
END;
```

**Edit**

More detailed

```
declare
opdatum varchar2(2000);  
opdiagnose varchar2(2000);  
d_op varchar2(2000); 
some_variable varchar2(2000); 
BEGIN   
   FOR rec IN (SELECT p.name, p.vorname, p.geburtsdatum, a.kis_id, kg.kg_id FROM kg_eintraege kg
   INNER JOIN aufenthalte a
   ON kg.patient_nr = a.patient_nr
   and kg.fall_nr = a.fall_nr
   INNER JOIN personen p
   ON a.patient_nr = p.pat_nr
   WHERE kg.kgtitel_nr = xxxxxxa
   and a.kis_id = xxxxxxb)  
    LOOP
        BEGIN
          Select kurztext into opdatum from kg_eintraege where kontext = rec.kg_id and kgtitel_nr = xxxxxxc;  
          Select text into opdiagnose from kg_eintraege where kontext = rec.kg_id and kgtitel_nr = xxxxxxd;  
          Select text into d_op from kg_eintraege where kontext = rec.kg_id and kgtitel_nr = xxxxxxe; 
          Select case when kurztext = 'Something' then '1' end into some_variable  from kg_eintraege where kontext = rec.kg_id and kgtitel_nr = xxxxxxf;   
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(rec.name || '    ' || rec.vorname || '    ' || TO_CHAR(rec.geburtsdatum, 'DD.MM.YYYY')
          || '    ' || rec.kis_id || '    ' ||  opdatum|| '    ' || opdiagnose || 
           '    ' || d_op || '    ' || some_variable 
          );     
          EXCEPTION
           WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
               some_variable := NULL;
               goto end_loop;     
        END;
        <<end_loop>>
        null;
    END LOOP; 
END;
```

**Update**

The case statement seems to be alright. The problem is that some rows in the select are null.

**Update2**

No exception needed.

Solution:

```
 select nvl((select case when kurztext = 'Something' then '1' end from kg_eintraege where kontext = rec.kg_id and kgtitel_nr = xxxxxxf and kurztext = 'Something'), 'NOT_FOUND') into some_variable from dual
```

Thanks to NikNik for the help.

Comment: What about `FOR rec IN (SELECT case when attribute = 'something' then '1' end AS FOO FROM somewhere where some_condition) LOOP`?

Comment: your loop tag <<end_loop>> is inside the loop.  it currently jumps to where it would end up anyway. can you show as data in your table

Comment: @Wernfried, I can't do that.

Comment: @Bennet
Unfortunately I can't for data protection reasons.

Comment: @SushiBlyat, your comments are quite weird. Why can you not re-write the SELECT statement? You should be able to provide some more realistic fake data,then you will get proper help.

Comment: @Wernfried
Yes, sir. I hope the edit above helps.

Comment: Yes, it helps but what is now your problem/question? Your code should work without any error.

Comment: Yes, that one works. But how does it work with the select case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is not the `CASE` but your `WHERE` condition witch is retourning more than 1 record or 0 record found.

For more details look [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01422.php).

In the second case you can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42415454/7604006):

```
select  nvl(  (your_case),  'NOT_FOUND'  )  into  foo  from dual;
```

Comment: How so? It works outside of the loop. And the other selects inside the loop have the same where condition with different values.

Comment: The different values in where condition can change the result. Try to put a case inside the working select (maybe the first 1 in for cycle)

Comment: ORA-01403 error appears again, when I put a case inside the first working select. What is your suggestion?

Comment: You probably don't have any record. Look at my update

Comment: <code>select nvl((select case when kurztext = 'Something' then '1' end from kg_eintraege where kontext = rec.kg_id and kgtitel_nr = xxxxxxf), 'NOT_FOUND') into some_variable from dual;</code>
You mean like this?