# Procedure Syntax Issue

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Pretty new to PL/SQL so apologies in advance. I am concerned about my syntax for a procedure I have made - using Oracle SQL Devloper

Here are the tables:

SALE_HEAD TABLE - https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l6Lf.jpg

CUSTOMER TABLE - https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F20d.jpg

```
create or replace procedure test2
(
x in Integer
) as
begin
SELECT into
((COUNT(sale_num))/4) FROM sale_head
INNER JOIN customer using(customer_id)
where status = 'S'
and SALE_DATE >= (add_months(SYSDATE, -12)) and customer_id= x;
end;
/
execute test2(81);
```

syntax as follows:

```
Error(6,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(6,8): PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Comment: What are you `SELECT`ing? What is `sale_num`?

Comment: `SELECT columns/expressions... INTO variable..FROM .. WHERE..` It is how the syntax goes! An Example [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163996/how-to-select-into-a-variable-in-pl-sql-when-the-result-might-be-null)

Comment: Hi @MaheswaranRavisankar. I have added the attachments of the tables http://imgur.com/YufJyto & http://imgur.com/ULXzpLc. I am selecting sale_num which is the attribute from the table sale_head as shown in the links given.

Comment: You are missing a variable name for `select into`. Please read the PL/SQL manual

Comment: @user2797402 - look at the outline Maheswaran gave and your statement - the structure is different... your `count()/4` should be before the `into`, and you should have `x` after the into, presumably. Not sure you really want `x` to be an integer if you might be putting a fraction into it though?

Comment: In general, people here aren't going to click on links as we're all aware of clickbait. I suggest you edit your question and include the definitions of the tables as text in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your SELECT statement is incorrect. The INTO clause is used to indicate the variable which is to receive the result of the SELECT. Try the following:

```
create or replace procedure test2(x in Integer) as
  nValue  NUMBER;
begin
  SELECT ((COUNT(sale_num))/4)
    INTO nValue
    FROM sale_head
    INNER JOIN customer using(customer_id)
    where status = 'S'
      and SALE_DATE >= (add_months(SYSDATE, -12))
      and customer_id = x;
end;
```

Share and enjoy.