# Select into variables when a column is null

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to `select` `into` variables with something like this :

```
select NAME, LASTNAME
into v_name, v_lastname
from PERSON;
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163996/how-to-select-into-a-variable-in-pl-sql-when-the-result-might-be-null), I can manage it with an `exception` `NO_DATA_FOUND`.

But how to do if `NAME` is `null`, but no `LASTNAME`, without two `select` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a matching line in the table, even when the values are `null`, the `select into` will just work, so I doubt there is really a problem with this statement when using the exception handling as described in the linked question. If there is a line, there will be no exception raised.

If you want to keep this statement working for both cases (with and without data in the table) without the exception handling, use a `left outer join`:

```
select NAME
,      LASTNAME
into   v_name
,      v_lastname
from   dual
left
outer
join   PERSON
on     1=1
;
```

I would suggest to keep the exception handling in place instead of using `left outer join`, since that is the most readable way in my opinion. Just to give you options.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about two separate things. Either:

1. The query doesn't return a row. In this case your PL/SQL will terminate unless you manage the exception with `NO_DATA_FOUND` as you said.
2. The query returns a row, but the values of `NAME` and/or `LASTNAME` are `null`. In this case the associated variable will simply be set to `null` where the value in the database is `null` - there's no exception to handle because a row was returned.

Incidentally, you might also want to consider using the `TOO_MANY_ROWS` exception. Your query must return one and only one row if you're selecting into variables, and your query as it stands (I appreciate it's maybe just a simplified example) has no `where` clause.