# ORACLE select into variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

This should be easy as answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553901/declaring-a-variable-and-setting-its-value-from-a-select-query-in-oracle) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163996/how-to-select-into-a-variable-in-pl-sql-when-the-result-might-be-null) are suggesting. But, I am receiving an error:

> ORA-00905: missing keyword
>   00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 7 Column: 36

My code:

```
vEXTERNAL_ACCOUNT_ID VARCHAR2(20);

  (SELECT EXTERNAL_ACCOUNT_ID INTO vEXTERNAL_ACCOUNT_ID FROM TOF_ORDER_DATA WHERE ID = 
 (SELECT TOF_ORDER_DATA_ID FROM TOF_WFI WHERE WFI_ID = 3466444));
```

All I want is to set vEXTERNAL_ACCOUNT_ID from query above (it returns only one result). I don't understand what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The parentheses around the select are completely useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is PL/SQL, so:

```
declare
  vexternal_account_id varchar2(20);
begin  
  select external_account_id 
    into vexternal_account_id 
    from tof_order_data 
    where id = (select tof_order_data_id 
                from tof_wfi 
                where wfi_id = 3466444
               );

  dbms_output.put_line('Value = ' || vexternal_account_id);
end;
```

- **declare** the variable
- use **begin**-**end** keywords
- remove outmost brackets
- in order to display value returned by query, use `dbms_output.put_line`

  - don't forget to `set serveroutput on` in tool you use!

Comment: That works. How to check for vexternal_account_id value? SELECT vexternal_account_id is throwing error.

Comment: Use `dbms_output.put_line`; I edited code I previously posted - have  a look.

Comment: I don't see any output. I am using sql developer. Sorry, it's ok - I've forgot to put serveroutput on.

Comment: As I said: execute `set serveroutput on` first to enable *output*. How? Just like that - copy that line into SQL Developer and execute it. Then run your PL/SQL code.